# Conditionally stop child rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart

In a stateful widget I have a navigation part where user can select Parent items,and below child items are shown.
when I select a parent is normal to rebuild child part too,but when I navigate throw Parent items without selecting one,the parent is rebuild(it is normal) but child widget is rebuild too,how to prevent child rebuild in this case?
thanks

Comment: Will this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134538/child-init-method-is-called-when-parent-is-rebuild-flutter be helpful?

Comment: Hi.I didn't find where to put rebuild condition

Answer (score 2):

[`didUpdateWidget()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) is called if the parent widget changes and has to rebuild this widget (because it needs to give it different data), but it's being rebuilt with the same runtimeType, then this method is called.

So you can try this:

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
  if (oldWidget.importantProperty != widget.importantProperty) {
    //TODO: Do some amazing stuff !!!
  }
}
```