# Flutter: How to stop Container recreating its child when decoration is changed

Tags: flutter

I have widgets like those below where one is a child of a container that sometimes has a decoration and sometimes doesnt. For some reason the child is getting recreated instead of just having its build method rerun.

```
class StatefulReproduction extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatefulReproduction({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StatefulReproductionState createState() => _StatefulReproductionState();
}

class _StatefulReproductionState  extends State<StatefulReproduction>{
  var timer;
  var counter = 0;
  @override
  initState() {
    print("setup reproduction");
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        counter = 1 + counter;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    print("cleaned up reproduction");
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
        child: StatefulChild(),
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: (counter % 2 == 0) ? Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 255)): null)
    );
  }
}

class StatefulChild extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulChild({super.key});

  @override
  _StatefulChildState createState() => _StatefulChildState();
}

class _StatefulChildState extends State<StatefulWidget>{

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init state called");
  }

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("hi");
  }
}
```

I want the stateful child to only print something once but instead its printing on every time tick which I think means its being recreated but I dont understand why or how I can stop this.

Comment: The `StatefulChild()` widget that you are using contains only one single `Text` widget. Why don't you convert the `StatefulChild` widget to a `Stateless` widget?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [child init method is called when parent is rebuild - flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134538/child-init-method-is-called-when-parent-is-rebuild-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Border.all(color: Colors.transparent) instead of null. You will not show a border on the screen but initState in the child widget will not be called

Comment: Colors.transparent doesnt seem to exist but Color.fromARGB(0,0,0,0) works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `const` keyword before the StatefulChild's constructor. And also mark this widget as `const` inside a Container:

```
return Container(
  child: const StatefulChild(),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: (counter % 2 == 0) ? Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 255)): null)
);
```

Comment: I have tried this one but it does not work